# How to update a column name in a table with another column in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have a table named `tUser`. The columns are:

- `UserID`
- `FirstName`
- `SecondName`
- `LastName`
- `Email`

I need to update `SecondName` with `FirstName` if it is Null. How can I do that?

Comment: give sample data with expected result

Comment: use `where` condition

Comment: Please read a SQL book before starting any project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
update tUser set SecondName=FirstName
where SecondName is null or SecondName ='NULL' or SecondName ='null'
```